# how to set icon to floating action button with flutter same this photo

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

how to set icon to floating action button with flutter same this photo
Please see the picture

[image: Image here]

Comment: what have you done so far, any tried code?

Comment: floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        elevation: 10,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.active_btn_Color,
        child: Container(
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: const AssetImage('assets/images/shop.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,

Comment: edit the code and paste the entire code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Badge plugin to achive that.
see the plugin : - [Badge plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

Use the badge property like this:-

```
    Badge(
      badgeContent: Text('3'),
      child: Icon(Icons.settings),
    )
```

You can wrap the floating action button with this.

Floating action button code:-

```
 floatingActionButton: Badge(
        badgeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 15, 87),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
        badgeContent: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Text(
            '3',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 15, 87),
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
```

**Full code**

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Badge(
        badgeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 15, 87),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
        badgeContent: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Text(
            '3',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 15, 87),
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Badge Button]

Comment: does this fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Stack your container with another upper-right corner container:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container( width: 30, height: 30, decoration: BoxDecoration( image: DecorationImage( image: const AssetImage('assets/images/shop.png'), fit: BoxFit.contain, ), ), ), ),
    Positioned(
      right: 20,
      top: 20,
      child: Container( width: 5, height: 5
  ]
```